# npgsql data type unknown when using group by

Tags: c#, postgresql, npgsql

I have 2 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE "book" 
(
  "id" serial PRIMARY KEY, 
  "ean_number" TEXT NULL, 
  "title" TEXT NULL 
); 

CREATE TABLE "e_book" 
(
  "id" serial PRIMARY KEY, 
  "ean" TEXT NULL, 
  "title" TEXT NULL, 
  "format" VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
  "physical_book_ean" TEXT NULL 
);
```

There is a one to many or none relationship from book to e_book.

I want to run a query like this in my code:

```
var q = "select b.*, array_agg(e) ebooks from book b " +
         "left join e_book e on e.physical_book_ean = b.ean_number " +
         "group by b.id";

using (var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(q, conn))
using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        //read data
    }
```

The array_agg column ebook comes up as content type `<unknown>`

How do I define the content type so I can read it?

Comment: Hi this issue about array types might be useful https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/1980

Comment: I saw that issue.  It was marked a bug. It has an associated commit a year ago and it is closed so that issue appears to be resolved.  It should support arrays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was opened as a github issue: https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/2510

The answer, as given there:

> First, if you create the e_book table and query it in the same process, you need to tell Npgsql to reload database type definitions. This is because when Npgsql first connects to a database, it loads the list of types and caches it - but at that point the e_book type doesn't exist yet. If you run your application again with the tables already there you should no longer have this issue, or you can call Npgsql.ReloadTypes().
>
> Second, you will need to pass the LoadTableComposites=true flag on the connection string, telling Npgsql to load all composite types - including those which correspond to tables. Npgsql doesn't do that by default since the number of tables can be massive and affect startup performance in some cases.