# When I run an Npgsql query using Dapper, why do I get "The field 'XYZ' has a type currently unknown to Npgsql"

Tags: asp.net, dapper, npgsql

I've created the following SQL view in my PostgreSql database (have simplified for brevity):

```
create view "GlossaryView" as 
select 
    (
        select cast(
            array_agg(
                cast(quals as "Qualification")
            ) as "Qualification"[]
        ) as "Qualifications" 
        from 
        (
            select * from "Qualification"
        ) as quals
    );
```

`Qualification` is a table in my database. Running a query against this view locally using `psql` works fine.

However, if I run the following query using Dapper:

```
connection.QueryAsync<dynamic>("select * from \"GlossaryView\" ");
```

I get the exception in the title, with `XYZ` replaced with `Qualifications`.

I came across this answer, which suggests using `LoadTableComposites=true` in the connection string:

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/56850677

However, when I include this in my connection string in my `appsettings.json` file, I get this exception during application startup:

> Keyword 'LoadTableComposites ' not supported

**Question:** How do I get the query working in Dapper? I suspect it's not really Dapper but Npgsql.

Npgsql version: 3.2.6

**Edit 1:** Here's the `Qualification` table structure:

```
          Table "public.Qualification"
 Column | Type | Collation | Nullable | Default 
--------+------+-----------+----------+---------
 Id     | uuid |           | not null | 
 Name   | text |           |          | 
Indexes:
    "PK_Qualification" PRIMARY KEY, btree ("Id")
Referenced by:
    TABLE ""User"" CONSTRAINT "FK_User_Qualification_QualificationId" 
        FOREIGN KEY ("QualificationId") REFERENCES "Qualification"("Id") ON DELETE CASCADE
```

Comment: Can you show the data types for the columns referenced in your query? It could be that the data type you are returning PostgreSQL is not handled by npgsql. https://www.npgsql.org/doc/types/basic.html

Comment: @EdMendez Thanks for that. Please see Edit 1.

Comment: The `Load Table Composites` option was only added in Npgsql 4.0. Can you please try 4.0.10 and report on the results? Also, just to make sure - is the Qualification table present in your database before the application starts, or is the table created by your application?

Comment: The `Qualification` table is present before app loads. Does `LoadTableComposite` also allow Npgsql to recognise composite types I create in the DB? ‘Cause I created a composite type with fields like the `Qualification` table and called this new type `QualificationType` and then instead of `Qualification`, I casted it to `QualificationType`. However I still get the same exception about type being unknown.

Comment: Once you return the type Qualification from the query what do you intend to do with the values? I am asking because I think you might have some hurdles parsing  the Type Qualification with npgsql and dapper. But there might be another way to accomplish what you need without the need of composite types.

Comment: @ShayRojansky Upgrading to 4.0.10 threw a bunch of errors which came down to updating Entity Framework Core as well. Once I did that, there were no issues with application start. However, queries now generate an error saying `Expected type System.UInt32 does not equal actual type System.UInt32`. The type for the column in question in the DB table is `oid`.

Comment: The best way forward here is to make everything work with the latest versions, rather than trying to look back to 3.2.x. For the new error (`Expected type System.UInt32...) please open a new question or issue with a minimal repro.

Answer (score 3):

Using Npgsql 4.0.10 and Dapper 2.0.4 the code snippet below should give you what you are requesting.

Notice I added the Load Composite Types into connection string as suggested in the comments and used Npgsql's typemapper to map the CLR type to the PostgreSQL type. You need to instantiate the connection as NpgsqlConnection instead of IDbConnection (normally suggested by Dapper).

When i created the testing objects for my snippet I didn't use quoted identifiers. You will need to adjust the snippet to compensate for the quoted identifiers in your implementation.

Information on Mapping CLR types can be found [here](https://www.npgsql.org/doc/types/enums_and_composites.html)

```
   public class QualificationType
    {
        public Guid Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using (NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection("Host=localhost;Database=postgres;username=postgres;password=!@#$%^&;Load Table Composites= true"))
            {
                conn.Open();
                conn.TypeMapper.MapComposite<QualificationType>("qualification");

                var results = conn.Query("Select * from glossaryview").AsList();

                var o = results[0].qualifications;

                foreach ( var t in o)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"id: {t.Id}, name: {t.Name}");
                }


            }
        }
    }
```

The results to that snippet returned the following;

```
id: d3c47de5-ab49-498e-be24-b77f8bb587fd, name: abc
id: 4089576a-d0a1-4570-b601-f54f98784ab2, name: def
id: 123e0722-9ade-48c7-937c-aa21214bee57, name: ghi
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I tried this but I get the exception "PostgreSQL composite type public.Qualification contains field Id which could not match any on CLR type QualificationType".

Comment: Note that the composite type can be mapped once globally, at the start of the program, rather than with each connection. See http://www.npgsql.org/doc/types/enums_and_composites.html.

Comment: @Ash Make sure in the conn.TypeMapper.MapComposite<QualificationType>("qualification") statement, that qualification matches your type in postgresql. It might be something like "\"Qualification\""